# Docker RUN fails but executing the same commands in the image succeeds

Tags: docker, qemu, nvidia-jetson

I'm working on a jetson tk1 deployment scheme where I use docker to create the root filesystem which then gets flashed onto the image.

The way this works is I create an armhf image using the nvidia provided sample filesystem with a qemu-arm-static binary which I can then build upon using standard docker tools.
I then have a "flasher" image which copies the contents of the file system, creates an iso image and flashes it onto my device.

The problem that I'm having is that I'm getting inconsistent results between installing apt packages using a docker RUN statement vs entering the image and installing apt packages.
IE:

```
# docker build -t jetsontk1:base .

Dockerfile


from jetsontk1:base1
RUN apt update
RUN apt install build-essential cmake
# or
RUN /bin/bash -c 'apt install build-essential cmake -y'
```

vs:

```
docker run -it jetsontk1:base1 /bin/bash
# apt update
# apt install build-essential cmake
```

When I install using the docker script I get the following error:

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::append
 qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
Aborted (core dumped)
The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/bash -c 'apt install build-essential cmake -y'' returned a non-zero code: 134
```

I have no issues when manually installing applications from when I'm inside the container, but there's no point in using docker to manage this image building process if I can't do apt installs :/

The project can be found here: https://github.com/dtmoodie/tk1_builder
With the current state with the issue as I presented it at commit: 8e22c0d5ba58e9fdab38e675eed417d73ae0aad9

Comment: How are you building it? What is the entry point of the Dockerfile going to be?

Comment: I've edited the original question, I am building with docker build -t jetsontk1:base .
The entry point for the filesystem image is not explicitly set so I believe it should just be a shell.